# moving from one fragment to another passing a string and an image

Tags: android

So Hello everyone, I want to be able to pass data between two fragments but when I call a toast method once I click the button it displays but when I click the button I get this error `$onFragmentInteraction.receivedStringandImage(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference`

this is my sample code, I have two TextInputLayout and a button to send the info to my first fragment.

```
private onFragmentInteraction frag1; 
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String object = extractText(edittext1);

                if (object != null){

                   frag1.receive(object);


                }else {

                }
            }
        });

my receive method on my first fragment.
 @Override
    public void receive(String object) {
        list.add(new Item(object, R.drawable.image1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`frag1` is not initialized and is hence throwing a null pointer exception when you use it to reference the receive function.

Follow this: [Deliver a Message to a Fragment](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Comment: This is how I did it    private onFragmentInteraction frag1;

Comment: Does it work? I believe that is causing the exception

Comment: says the problem is this line  frag1.receive(object); I was wondering could it be because I am using an image and string?